# Measure of image of an absolutely continuous function and its integrals

Tags: measure-theory, change-of-variable

Consider an absolutely continuous function $F:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
One can find a function $f\in L^1([a,b],m)$, where $m$ is a Lebesgue measure, such that $F(x)-F(a)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$.

I am curious about whether $m(F(E))=\int_Ef(t)dt$ for any $E\subset[a,b]$.If so, how can I prove it?

Comment: For $F(x)=x$ there is no such $f$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry, I edited the question

Comment: $F(x)=x^{2}, a=-1,b=1, E=[-1,1]$ is a counter-example.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you! I will finish this question using your answer. Can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, without further assumptions, the claim is false.

However, if $F$ is non-decreasing and $E$ is a Borel-measurable set of $[a,b]$, the result is true.

In fact, let $\mathcal{E}$ be the set of all Borel-measurable subsets $E$ of $[a,b]$ for which the result is true, i.e., $E \in \mathcal{E}$ if and only if $E\subset [a,b]$ is Borel measurable and
\begin{equation}
   m\big(F(E)\big) = \int_E f\mathrm{d}m.
\end{equation}
Then $\mathcal{E}$ is a [$\lambda$-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#Definitions) that contains the set $\mathcal{I}$ of the open intervals (in the relative topology) of $[a,b]$. But $\mathcal{I}$ is a [$\pi$-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system) that generates the Borel subsets of $[a,b]$. By the [$\pi-\lambda$ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#Dynkin%27s_%CF%80-%CE%BB_theorem), we have that $\mathcal{E}$ coincides with the Borel subset of $[a,b]$, i.e., for every Borel subset $E$ of $[a,b]$ it holds that
\begin{equation}
   m\big(F(E)\big) = \int_E f\mathrm{d}m.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much!!